# How to make apache(CentOS8) virtual host rewrite rule for https subdomain?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, centos8

I have https domain as an example .

https://example.com

I can access this domain as well. Then, I create subdomain from domain registration provider, e.g https://subdomain.example.com. But I can not access because of 'Not Secure' alert. I think, cause from my virtual host rewrite rule. Below is my config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName example.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public 
 <Directory /var/www/html/example> 
    AllowOverride All 
 </Directory> 
    RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
    https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: That message your browser throws indicates that most likely your SSL certificate is not valid for that subdomain. Or that you did not configure any certificate for that subdomain. You can check the certificate in your browser. Keep in mind that certificates need to either explicitly name the host name they are used for (multiple host names are possible, so here domain and subdomain), or you need a "wildcard domain" that covers all potential subdomains. So you probably need to add the subdomain to the certificate, that is possible with lets encrypt certificates.

Comment: Dear arkascha, thank you for information. I'm really newbie.